# Pushing code in to BitBucket using Ubuntu system with Tortoisehg

Tags: android, bitbucket, tortoisehg

Am using Ubuntu system.In windows i can easy to add code in to BitBucket using source tree.But in Ubuntu i need to use TortoiseHg.I have created new repository and all but when am trying to add my path it showing 404 error?

1. How can i add project in to BItBucket?
2. Please provide step by step procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

1.Create repository in bit bucket

open your terminal and follow this step

1.cd /path/to/your/repo

2.sudo apt-get install git

3.if git exists then-> rmdir .git/

4.git init

5.git remote add origin https://username@bitbucket.org/your user name/your repository.git

6.git add .

7.git commit -am "first commit"

8.git push -u origin master

9.then enter your user name hit enter then enter password